# Unit Testing Local Asp WebForm

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, unit-testing, selenium

I am new at unit testing. The tool I am using is Selenium webdriver in visual studio
For practice I initially redirected to different Urls and tested their controls to find that the working is correct. Then I created my own Asp webform for the testing purpose. So what I want now is to redirect to the localhost web form in the test method which I am not able to do.
even if I do so:

```
    [TestMethod]

    public void TestAspForm()
    {
        driverGC.Url = ("http://localhost:55311/AspForm.aspx");
     }
```

The page never loads.I get the following:
[image] Can someone please guide me??

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to run server, then run test. It seems that you dont have server runned.

its navigating to your page.

```
ChromeDriver driver;
[TestMethod]    
public void TestAspForm()
{
   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:55311/AspForm.aspx");
}
```

try `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.google.com");` and you will see that its navigating properly to page.

Comment: please view the image attached

Comment: I edited my answer. You dont have running server. If you switch
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:55311/AspForm.aspx");
to 
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.google.com"); you will be navigated to Google page.

Comment: how to get my server into running form?

Comment: No. even when navigating to url it doesnot